# How to register CONTROL-D in my Python program? I want it to register as a EOFERROR when the user input control-d but it registers it as a string (^d)

Tags: python, eoferror

```
x = set()

#items stored here to display by adding items from x

display_list = []

#items stored here to be counted

count_list = []

while True:
   
    items = input("> ").upper()
    if items != "Q":
        x.add(items)
        count_list.append(items)
        count_list.count(items)

    elif items == "Q":
        display_list.extend(x)
        display_list.sort()
        for items in display_list:
            print(f"{count_list.count(items)} {items}")
        exit()
```

Comment: Beside the point, but there's no point having `count_list.count(items)` on its own there. It calculates the result, but with nothing there to receive it, it just gets thrown away.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) for tips like making a [mre] including input and output.

Comment: Also beside the point, but you could simplify this a lot by removing `display_list` and just doing `for item in sorted(x):` And BTW, I made it `item`, in singular, since the name is for *each* item in the list, not *all* items at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl+D is the sequence in Linux and MacOS. For the equivalent in Windows you need to do `Ctrl+Z` followed by `<Enter>`

Then you'll need to change your code so that instead of checking for an input of "Q", you need to wrap your input() call in a `try: / except EOFERROR:` block